# Offset changes based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

I have written code to **navigate** to a specific section using following java-script:

Following anchor links are **clicked** , it will redirect to specific section of different page:

```
<a href="getinvolved/#voluntours" data-toggle="" data-target="" target="" class="button">Voluntours</a>
<a href="getinvolved/#dreamcourts" data-toggle="" data-target="" target="" class="button">Dreamcourts</a>
```

Following shows the target **page html**:

```
<div id="voluntours" class="volunteer-days" style="padding-top: 25px;">
    <p>some text1</p>
    <p>some text2</p>
    <p>some text3</p>
    <p>some text4</p>
    <p>some text5</p>
</div>

<div id="dreamcourts" class="volunteer-days" style="padding-top: 25px;">
    <p>some text1</p>
    <p>some text2</p>
    <p>some text3</p>
    <p>some text4</p>
    <p>some text5</p>
</div>
```

**Following script will navigate to the target page:**

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("getinvolved")) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
        var id = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("#"));
        var ofs = 0;
        if(id.indexOf("voluntour") > -1) {
            ofs = $(id).offset().top;
        } else if(id.indexOf("dreamcourts") > -1) {
            ofs = $(id).offset().top + 250;    
        } else {
            ofs = $(id).offset().top;
        }
    }
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: ofs });
}
```

Issue is it works fine in developer screen, but when the scree size changes, offset changes and navigation will go to a wrong area.

Even offset keep changing after each page refresh as well.

Could you please advice, how to fix this issue?

Comment: try to replace `250` with `$("#voluntour").height()` in the script

Comment: its not working any clue?

Comment: so you need to set `position: fixed` for navigation block

Comment: Not working......